# Android Studio Unit Testing Configuration

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, jenkins, ui-testing

Is there a way to run Android unit tests or configurations from the command line? Currently "gradle test" runs all the tests within the Unit Tests test artifact but these fail with the error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation."

I am looking for a way to run the same configuration that is run when right clicking the com.foo.android(test) and pressing "Run tests in 'com.foo.android'" within Android Studio? I am looking to move this to Jenkins. Or be able to use the configuration that I created manually in AS.

Thanks

[**EDIT**]
If I separate the pure junit unit tests and Instrumentation tests into their respective artifacts then I lose the ability to run the UI tests on their own, is there a way around this? I have a configuration the only runs the UITest package but do not know how to run this configuration from the command line.

Comment: Do you have instrumented tests (e.g. Espresso tests), or just pure Java junit  tests?

Comment: Mix of both, they are not all separated out either, some are within the same classes

Comment: Have you configured a `testInstrumentationRunner` in your build.gradle?

Comment: testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" is how it is setup currently

Answer (score 0):

See if these will help running android unit tests from the command line:

```
adb shell am instrument -w <package>/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

Running All test cases in the sub package:

```
adb shell am instrument -w  <package>.<sub package>/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

Running Single test case from the test class:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e class <project>.<test class>#testCase
<package>/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

Comment: this will work for packages, however is there a way to run a configuration, instead of specifying each package individually? If not, I could probably just create a package specifically for unitTests, InstrumentationTests, and UITests.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I have found to do it is to have all of my UITests in a package and when I only want to run unit tests run:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e notPackage com.foo.android.UITest com.foo.android.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

to run all tests run:

```
adb shell am instrument -w com.foo.android.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

for only UITest:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e package com.foo.android.UITest com.foo.android.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```